# How can i add AccesToken to header and send request iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have sent a request with the access token. I got an error response.

```
[Response]:
    [Status Code]: 401
  
   {"response":{"success":"false","result":{"errorCode":"4012001002","message":"Invalid token / expired."}}}
```

below I have added code...

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
class HelpViewController: UIViewController{

var ticketResult = [TicketResponse]()

let tokens: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "accessToken")
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    HistoryAPI()
}

func HistoryAPI() {
    if tokens != nil
    {
        print("Hello Access Token \(String(describing: tokens))")
            let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "correlationId": "myYt005",
                "operation": "ticketDetail",
                "destination": "CRM",
                "source": "WEB",
                "srDate": "16-05-2022",
                "token": "\(String(describing: tokens))"
                //   "token": "\(String(describing: token))"
            ]
        
            AF.request(ticketHistory_url, method: .get,  headers: headers).response { response in
                
                debugPrint(response)
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                 
                    if let ticketData = data as? [TicketResponse] {
                        self.ticketResult = ticketData
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    // Handle the error if needed
                }}}
    }
}
```

Comment: `"\(String(describing: tokens))"` -> `token!`?, but id be better to use a `if let`

Comment: What's the doc on sending the token? Is it really `"token: myToken"`, or is it, like more standard "Authorization: myToken", or "Authorization: Bearer myToken", etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the correct token header key, "Authorization"

```
"Authorization": "Bearer \(accessToken)"
```

Comment: source: WEB
        srDate: 16-05-2022
        token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0ZW5hbnRUeXBlIjoiY2xpZW50IiwidGVuYW5jeUlkIjoiTVZOT19XRUJfUFRDIiwibG9naW5Vc2VybmFtZSI6Ijk2NzEwMTAxMDg3OSIsImxvZ2luVHlwZSI6ImRldmljZUlkIiwiYXBwSWQiOiI2YThjZjI3MC1jMzI4LTM1NzktYjM2NS05YTU5N2RlNzUyYWIiLCJhY2NvdW50Tm8iOiJTQTEyMjg4OTAiLCJ0b2tlblR5cGUiOiJ1c2VyVG9rZW4iLCJleHAiOjE2ODk4ODg5MDksImlhdCI6MTY4OTg0NTcwOSwiZW1haWwiOiJtb2JpbGVhcHAxMjNAeW9wbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.gV6-RrfvUqDyYMrOIRfkhofUooHcXl0sd-eLid50V4CnBOBupz9130CjyE31mTaOiwzQhkK2VAlA57BYvSJE_A

Comment: let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                    "correlationId": "myYt005",
                    "operation": "ticketDetail",
                    "destination": "CRM",
                    "source": "WEB",
                    "srDate": "16-05-2022",
                    "token": "Bearer \(tokens)"
                  
                ]

Comment: {"response":{"success":"false","result":{"errorCode":"4012001002","message":"Invalid token / expired."}}}

Comment: Could it be the token is simply expired?